# What is the best way to parallelise tasks sharing an object but otherwise independent?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm coding a physics simulation consisting mainly of a central loop of hundreds of billions of repetitions of operations on an array. These operations are independent from the other (well actually the array changes along the way) and so I'm thinking about parallelising my code as I can make it run on 4 or 8 cores computers in my lab.
It's my first time doing something alike and I've been advised to look at openmp. I've started to code some toy programs with it, but I'm really unsure about how it works and the documentation is quite cryptic to me. For example the following code:

```
int a = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
  {
    a++;
  }
   cout << a << endl;
```

launched on my computer (4 cores CPU) gives me sometimes 4, other times 3 or 2. Is it because it doesn't wait for all the cores to execute the instructions? Because I sure need to know how many iterations were done in my case. Should I look for something else than openmp considering what I want in the end?

Comment: The operations are independent <=> the array changes along the way. No, they are not independent if the result of one operation affects the inputs of the next operation.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas for sure: what I meant is that it is actually probabilistic and for 4 operations each one going to one of the cores, the probability that two of them use the same part of the array is 10^(-6) so quite negligible.

Comment: Is it fine if you get unlucky and the different tasks stomp on each other data? I mean, if you don't care about correctness you can probably make your program go blazzing fast

Comment: For programs with the approximate outline you have shown OpenMP's *reduction* operations may be useful.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas What do you mean by stomp? What happens in this precise case?

Comment: In the small percentage of cases where they do modify the same data, what happens if two threads write to the same data, what happens if one thread modifies the data that is being processed by the other? Are you *fine* with that race condition trashing your results (note that you may not even know if this happened)?

Comment: Thank you for explaining me this memory conflict. Hum... yes I'm willing to take the risk considering the low probability of it to happen, and that I have more important (for now) uncertainties on my results coming from statistical fluctuations ;)

Answer (score 0):

When writing concurrently to a shared variable (`a` in your code), you have a data race. To avoid different threads writing "simultaneously", you must either use an atomic assignment or protect the assignment with a *mutex* (= mutual exclusion). In OpenMP, the latter is done via a *critical region*

```
int a = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp critical
  {
    a++;
  }
}
cout << a << endl;
```

(of course, this particular program does nothing in parallel, hence will be slower than a serial one doing the same).

For more info, read the openMP documentation! However, I would advise you to not use OpenMP, but TBB if you're using C++. It's much more flexible.

Comment: Don't expect this approach to result in a parallel program which executes more quickly than the serial version.  My untested expectation is that it would actually be slower.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes, of course. That was not the point. The point here was how to deal with a simple data race.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark My program is simply that from the question with a critical region added.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the typical example of a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Four threads are trying to increment variable `a` and they are fighting for it. Some 'lose' and they are not able to increment so you see a result lower than 4.

What happens is that the `a++` command is actually a set of three instructions: read `a` from memory and put it in a register, increment the value in the register, then put the value back in memory. If thread 1 reads the value of `a` after thread 2 has read it but before thread 2 has written the new value back to `a`, the increment operation of thread2 will be overwritten. Using `#omp critical` is a way to ensure that all the read/increment/write operations are not interrupted by another thread.

If you need to parallelize iterations, you can use `omp parallel for`, for instance to increment all the elements in an array.

Typical use:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        a[i]++;
```